# does recursive wget download visited URLs?

Tags: bash, recursion, wget

I want to use wget to recursively download a complete webpage. If for example, pages on level 2 of depth contains links to pages from level 1 (that have been already downloaded), will wget download them again? If so, is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Will a manual wget-like script be more optimal than wget, or is it optimised to avoid downloading things over and again? (I'm especially worried about menu links that appear on all pages)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single wget run should never try to download the same page twice.  It wouldn't be very useful for mirroring if it did.  :)  It also has some other failsafes, like refusing to recurse to another domain or a higher directory.

If you want to be sure it's doing the right thing, I suggest just trying it out and watching what it does; you can always mash `^C`.